# Docker Desktop Installer stop

Tags: docker, installation

I downloaded the Docker Desktop installer.exe from https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop/. I clicked on it to run as administrator, but the "Installing Docker Desktop 4.18.0" window appears blank and closes after a few seconds.

Furthermore, I have tried all of these solutions, but to no avail:

1. Verify that your computer meets the minimum requirements for Docker
   Desktop.
2. Ensure that your operating system is up-to-date, and all critical
   patches are installed.
3. Temporarily disable your firewall and antivirus.